# Surjectivity of function in the functional equation $f \big(xf (y)-f(x)\big)=2f (x)+xy $

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I came across the following question while studying functional equations.

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a function satisfying
> $$f \big(xf (y)-f(x)\big)=2f (x)+xy $$
> $\forall x, y \in \mathbb {R} $, prove that $f $ is a surjective function.

I really have no idea that how to prove the aforementioned as I am very new to functional equations.
The author has provided a very short proof without mentioning much details, making it very confusing and difficult to understand.

A pedantic proof would be highly helpful and will really be appreciated.

Thank you

Best regards !

Comment: Pleas quote the proof given by the author and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Actually the proof by author is of only 4 lines and  I am not able to understand it as a whole......i am in a need of a new pedantic and detailed proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we fix $x = 1$, then the equation becomes
$$f(f(y) - f(1)) = 2f(1) + y,$$
for any $y$. Intuitively, the right hand side can be made to be any value we want. The left hand side is $f$ of some expression of $y$ (it doesn't really matter what). So, we can choose a value of $y$ to make the right hand side whatever we want, then we have $f$ of an expression of $y$ that produces this value. This is what makes $f$ surjective.

If we want to prove it formally, fix $b \in \Bbb{R}$. Let $x = 1$ and $y = b - 2f(1)$. Then our equation turns into
$$f(f(b - f(1)) - f(1)) = 2f(1) + b - 2f(1) = b.$$
If we let $a = f(b - f(1)) - f(1)$, then we have constructed an $a \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(a) = b$, proving surjectivity.

Comment: I guess, you meant to take $2f (1)+y=b $ ??

Comment: Could you please explain me that why did you choose  to fix $x=1$ but not $y $ ??

Comment: Well, we don't get to set $b$. The point of $b$ is to be an arbitrary real number, over which we have no control, and to choose a real number $a$, over which we have complete control, such that $f(a) = b$. So, I can't set $b = 2f(1) + y$, but I can let $y = b - 2f(1)$, as $y$ is a dummy variable in the functional equation, and hence we can set it to anything we like. But, the end result is the same: $y = b - 2f(1)$ or equivalently, $b = y + 2f(1)$.

Comment: As for your second question, I'd like to refer you back to my "Intuitively..." paragraph. By setting $x = 1$, the right hand side turns into a surjective function of $y$. If we had selected $y = 1$ instead, then the right hand side turns into $2f(x) + x$, which may or may not be surjective (e.g. what if $f(x) = -x/2$?). By setting $x = 1$, it turns $f(x)$ into a constant term, and the right hand side is clearly surjective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help  !

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I have one last question.                      Suppose that we have a function $f:\mathbb {R}\to \mathbb {R}$, such that  $f (f (x))=f (f (0))-x $. Then we can prove that $f $ is surjective in the same way as you did above. We can take $x=f (f (0))-b $ and we get $f (f (f (f (0))-b))=b$. And then by substituting  $f (f (f (0))-b)=a \in \mathbb {R}$, we get $f (a)=b $ proving the surjectivity.                                                       Am I right ?..please let me know.

Comment: @user832197 Yes, you are right. It works exactly the same way.

Comment: Could you please help to prove that $f $ is surjective where $f (a+2f (a)f (b))=f (a)+2af (b) $ and $f:\mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R}$ ??

Comment: It may not be, if $f \equiv 0$. If you want help with another problem, I'd suggest asking another question. If you post a message here, I can take a look at it when I get the time.